# Google Slide API getting oauth2Client.getToken

Tags: google-slides-api

I am following this tutorial from Google Slide API.
[Google Slide](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/slides-api/#3)
After setting up Google project etc I run the code but it stops here and asking this questions:
"Enter the code from that page here"

Where do I get this code?
It also opens my document folder in Windows 10 when it gets here.

Answer (score 0):

On the line before, It will give you a link, copy and paste that link into your browser and it will give you a code. The code will be a long string of gibberish made up of letters and numbers. Paste that code back into command prompt/terminal.